# Accessing another class within a class in maui xaml

Tags: maui

C# :

```
namespace JsonData.Model
{
    public class Data
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" // "Results" ObservableCollection
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Data">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Name}" />   // Binding: Property "Name" not found on "JsonData.Model.Data" error occurs here
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Hi friends,

As in the example above, I cannot access a member of another class that exists within the class in XAML. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I can easily reach members in non-nested class.

Note: I also tried this:

`<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Result">`

Thank you in advance to those who will help.

Comment: Why do you have class nested inside another class? What's the purpose of this? Where and how do you create instances of the `Data.Result` type and how is `Results` defined? Have you tried `x:DataType="model:Data.Result"` (not sure if that's possible in XAML)?

Comment: Yes, I tried the possible steps you showed, but I couldn't find a solution. I also have two different jason sources with the same member names. I chose this way to avoid conflict. Of course, there are different ways I can solve this problem. But I was actually curious about the situation on Xaml.

Comment: Data does not have a property Name.  Data does not have any properties defined.

Comment: @Jason It does not accept either: <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Result"> and <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Data.Result">

Comment: Don’t nest classes.  I can’t think of any good reason for doing that

Comment: @Jason I'm really aware of this situation, but don't you wonder if there's a way around this?

Comment: Possibly.  I don't have time to try it out, and you haven't posted enough code for me to tell if you might be doing something else wrong

Comment: Your `Data` class is missing a `public Result Result { get; set; }`. If you add that, then you can freely do Bindings to `Result.Name` and `Result.Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see from your code is that you are deserialize json. So the main structure ends up as a class, `Data` in your case. The rest of the structur should ends up as list to access that result data. So your Class Structure should be (this should perhaps be done is other ways , but given what we know):

```cs
public class Data
{
    public IList<Result> Results { get; set; } = new List<Result>();

    public class Result
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your `ViewModel` is this:

```cs
public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data.Result> Results { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Results = new ObservableCollection<Data.Result>
        {
            new Data.Result { Id = 1, Name = "Alice Smith" },
            new Data.Result { Id = 2, Name = "Bob Johnson" },
            new Data.Result { Id = 3, Name = "Carol Williams" }
        };
    }
}
```

Your `CollectionView`

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="5">
                <Button Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Alternativ**

But let us say we have more data in the Data class. Then we have to do the complete dataset

The class would perhaps be like

```cs
public class Data
{
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public IList<Result> Results { get; set; } = new List<Result>();

    public class Result
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Dataset { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Dataset = new ObservableCollection<Data>
        {
            new Data
            {
                DataId = 100,
                Results = new List<Data.Result>
                {
                    new Data.Result { Id = 1, Name = "Alice Smith" },
                    new Data.Result { Id = 2, Name = "Bob Johnson" }
                }
            },
            new Data
            {
                DataId = 101,
                Results = new List<Data.Result>
                {
                    new Data.Result { Id = 3, Name = "Carol Williams" },
                    new Data.Result { Id = 4, Name = "David Brown" }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Dataset}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding DataId}" />
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Button Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]